# how can I change App bar navigation button and text color?

Tags: android, material-design, appbar

I am not getting the color of app bar's text and navigation color.
Here is my style file.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="chipIconTint">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>

    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">

        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

    </style>
```

I have primaryDark color as #FF1236(red), primary as While and accent is black.
Here is the color file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#ff1236</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#000000</color>
    <color name="colorPupUpBack">#EFEFEF</color>
    <color name="colorFB">#3B5998</color>
    <color name="colorGoogle">#db3236</color>
    <color name="colorLoginStatus">#FAFAFA</color>
    <color name="colorPhone">#0f9b8e</color>
    <color name="colorDots">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="colorBottom">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="dot_light_screen1">#FF1236</color>
    <color name="dot_light_screen2">#FF1236</color>
    <color name="dot_light_screen3">#FF1236</color>
    <color name="dot_light_screen4">#FF1236</color>
    <color name="about_color">#a9a8a8</color>
    <color name="color_nnavtext">#a5a5a5</color>
    <color name="transparent">#00FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="colorWhite">#FFFFFF</color>
```

Here is the manifest file. The main activity has toolbar and other activities have action bar.

```
<application
        android:name=".CardLoading"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:icon, android:appComponentFactory"
        android:appComponentFactory="@string/app_name"
        >

        <!-- Firebase InstanceId Service -->

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Profile"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".PersonalDetails"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".CartActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".UserCheckout"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Payment"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".UserCheckout" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".OrderPlacedActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".WelcomeActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Orders"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".AboutCofoz"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity" />
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBnu-jaUA2ETFeAJ1UVgetENVnaOqxrcGo" />

        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".RecipeCard"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

I am using metarial theme

Comment: Can you show  your manifest

Comment: I have edited my question with manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

try this, hope this will help you.

```
    <style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
                <item name="spinBars">true</item>
                <item name="color">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
                <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```